# Calling a function with scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I am trying to run the following code:

```
(define (myadd x y)
    (+ x y)
)

(myadd '(3 4))
```

But, I am getting the following error:

```
Error: +: number required, but got (3 4) [myadd, +]
```

How do I get the myadd function to return 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you should call your procedure:

```
(myadd 3 4) ; option 1
```

Because it expects *two* parameters, `x` and `y`, that get bound to `3` and `4` in the example. This won't work:

```
(myadd '(3 4))
```

The above is passing a *single* argument - a list with two elements. Not only is the number of arguments wrong, also the type, as the procedure is expecting two numbers.

Now, if the two values you want to pass to the `myadd` procedure come as a list from somewhere else, you have two options to pass them along, either explicitly extract them:

```
(define args '(3 4))
(myadd (car args) (cadr args))  ; option 2
```

Or use [`apply`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._apply%29%29) to invoke your procedure with a list:

```
(apply myadd '(3 4))  ; option 3
```

Any of the three options detailed above will return a value of `7`, but I'm betting you're just interested in the simplest one, which is option #1.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `apply` function to spread a list into separate arguments:

```
(apply myadd '(3 4))
```